# Scanning GZIP compressed Qr Code using Firebase ML Kit

Tags: android, gzip, qr-code, zxing, firebase-mlkit

***I am trying to scan a Qr code's Binary value which is GZIP compressed,but I am getting unknown encoding from most of the scanner.***

> QR VALUE: ABCDEFGHI, UTF-8 encoding,GZIP Compressed.

I tried doing the same with zxing,zbar and now ML Kit. Response after detection is "UNKNOWN ENCODING TYPE".I heard we need to develop our own scanner to do this.How will I go ahead to implement this? How will I scan a compressed Gzip Qr code, do any other scanners helps for this problem? [image: Image - QR VALUE: ABCDEFGHI, UTF-8 encoding,GZIP Compressed]

**Used ZXING,ZBAR,GOOGLE MOBILE VISION and ML KIT, no expected output**

Comment: Google didn't support all the encoding type 
try this instead https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

Comment: ok i will check that

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery Its a good library liked it, but doesn't help to scan gzip code.

Comment: try the other repos on github
https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=QR&s=stars&type=Repositories